# How to handle TimeoutException with ExecutorService and Futures?

Tags: java, exception, executorservice

I have the following example code and let's say that `MyCallable("B")` takes longer than one second to execute, when the others execute quicker than one second. Therefore inside my loop that calls `Future.get()`, it will throw a `TimeoutException`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();

    futures.add(es.submit(new MyCallable("A")));
    futures.add(es.submit(new MyCallable("B")));
    futures.add(es.submit(new MyCallable("C")));
    futures.add(es.submit(new MyCallable("D")));
    futures.add(es.submit(new MyCallable("E")));

    try {
        for(Future<String> f  : futures) {
            try {
                System.out.println("result " + f.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
            }
            catch (TimeoutException e) {
                // how do I know which MyCallable() has timed out?
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        es.shutdown();
    }
}
```

As expected each of the MyCallable() instances execute, but for the one that times out I would like to perform some error handling and this requires knowing which `Callable` is associated with which `Future`.

Is there a mechanism for this association or is it up to my `Callable` to handle all the error processing inside it's `call()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could simply maintain a `Map<Future<String>, Callable<String>>` instead of a `List<Future<String>>` and retrieve the original Callable that way.

If you want to get really clever, you could do it OO-style and extend ThreadPoolExecutor and create a Future decorator class. I think this is probably overkill, but you could do it like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;


public class FutureWithCallable<T> implements Future<T> {
    private final Callable<T> callable;
    private final Future<T> wrapped;

    public FutureWithCallable(Future<T> wrapped, Callable<T> callable) {
        this.callable = callable;
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public Callable<T> getCallable() {
        return callable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        return wrapped.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
    }

    @Override
    public T get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        return wrapped.get();
    }

    @Override
    public T get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException,
            ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        return wrapped.get(timeout, unit);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return wrapped.isCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDone() {
        return wrapped.isDone();
    }
}
```

And then:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    public class ExecutorServiceWithCallable extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

        public ExecutorServiceWithCallable(int corePoolSize, int maxPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
            super(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
        }

        @Override
        public <T> FutureWithCallable submit(Callable<T> callable) {
            Future<T> future = super.submit(callable);
            return new FutureWithCallable<T>(future, callable);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Using `Map<Future<String>, Callable<String>>` is the simplest option and works

Answer (score -1):

public class TimeoutException
extends Exception
Exception thrown when a blocking operation times out. Blocking operations for which a timeout is specified need a means to indicate that the timeout has occurred. For many such operations it is possible to return a value that indicates timeout; when that is not possible or desirable then TimeoutException should be declared and thrown.